# Литература по уязвимостям

Tags: python, уязвимости, django, защита, книги

Не подскажите, где можно прочитать про различные уязвимости у интернет проектов? Делаю небольшой сайт на Django. Хочется заранее устранить проблемы.

Answer (score 2):

Ну что же Вы не задаете поисковикам соответствующий запрос? Вот вам статья 2008 г.: [атаки против сайтов](http://blog.artus.ru/ataki-protiv-sajtov/).

Answer (score 2):

**Защита от sql-инъекций**, на своём примере:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
} //id "хозяина" странички
else {
    exit("Вы зашил на страницу без параметра!");
} //если не указали id, то выдаем ошибку
if (!preg_match("|^[\d]+$|", $id)) {
    exit("<p>Неверный формат запроса! Проверьте URL</p>"); //если id не число, то выдаем ошибку
}
```

**Защита от DDoS-атак**, тоже на своём примере, но там нет ничего трудного, чтобы изменить под себя. Создаете в корневом каталоге файл .htaccess и пишете туда с подменой домена на свой:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?site.ru/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|js|css|zip|rar|ico|html|php)$ - [F]
```

**Защита от эксплоитов.** Допустим, на странице редактирования данных о пользователе в какое-нибудь поле для текста можно вставить, например, какой-нибудь ява-скрипт код, который будет работать при заходе на страницу пользователя. И чтоб этого избежать пользуемся htmlspecialchars(), stripslashes(), trim(). Если пользователь введёт какой-нибудь код, то он будет просто отображаться, но не работать.

Comment: Кирилл, без обид но ваши методы защиты это деский садик. Кстати существуют функции is_numeric(), is_string(). И не стоит пугать пользователей всякими Вы преперлись без параметра! Им это нафиг не нужно. 404 это самый адекватный ответ в таких слычаях, потому что поисковики очень часто любят припереться с всякими интересными параметрами, а потом все это еще и в индексацию сайта пойдет. Так что советую вам по дружески, прекращайте эти шуточки, хакер от этих сообщений от страха не умрет, я вам гарантирую.

Comment: ну да). с инъекциями по детски. но от ддос-атак и эксплоит - нормально же?

Answer (score 1):

Я как правило читаю описания на сайтах поддержки, и таким образом нахожу новое для себя. Вот например полистайте [документацию](http://wiki.iblink.ru/) одного из популярных форумов.